# How can I reload recycleview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-java2

This is my scenario:

`Viewpager` has two `Fragment`s. Including `HistoryFragment`, which loads a `RecycleView` on creation.

I go ahead and add an item to the database from another `Activity`, however, it doesn't refresh the `RecycleView`, I need to close the app and load it again to see it refreshed.

How would you handle this?

RxJava? How would I notify the listener a changed occurred? Or do I simply reload the `Fragment`? (if so, how would I do that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I notify the listener a changed" you almost answered yourself. You need to use the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) adapter's function `notifyDataSetChanged()` (see this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())) when an update has been made in your database to reload view's content with new data.
You have not provided any code but I think it is the missing line you need to make it work

Answer (score 3):

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: change the data set before !

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for reload whole fragment...

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                ft.detach(YourFragmentName.this).attach(YourFragmentName.this).commit();
```